# How do I kill a process and ensure that port bindings are cleaned up?

Tags: kill

I have a situation where I kill a process, but when restarting it, I get the `Address already in use` error.

I am running `sudo netstat -lntp` to get the process ID, which returns, for example:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8002            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN       475/valhalla_servic
```

I then run  `sudo kill -9 475`

After running this, `netstat` no longer shows the process, but when I try to restart I receive the Address already in use error and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why `kill -9`? Does the same happen with signals other than KILL?

Comment: The netstat command you ran didn't show you a process.  "lsof -Pn" might.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille `-p` mean exactly process!!! check man of `netstat`

Comment: Try running the process through strace to see what it is actually trying to do. Also verify that port 8002 is free before restarting.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Good news: nothing.

The TCP state machine has timeout conditions. For that reason, ports linger a while, by default.

As a user of some software, there's not much you can do about that - not letting arbitrary software instantly rebind a port is, in the end, also a security feature.

As a developer of the software, you can [set `SO_LINGER` to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757289/when-is-tcp-option-so-linger-0-required). It is, in most cases, not the right thing to do – especially not when you do actually kill the owning process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I don't think that's the issue in my case as I can leave it for many hours and still see Address already in use

Comment: then you didn't kill the process(es) that hold the socket

Comment: If it isn't killed, it should be shown in the above call to netstat shouldn't it? Once I issue the kill command, there is nothing showing there. (Thanks again for the answer / follow up)

Comment: good point. does anything show up with `-a` instead of `-l`? if so, what does its STATE column say? (btw, `netstat` is a bit old by now, `ss` is the "moderner" alternative on Linux, at least)

Comment: Nope, it is like all trace of the process is gone and yet I still receive the error on restart